# Questions related to paid modules (non free)?

Tags: support

Just wondering if we can post questions related to paid modules like this: http://codecanyon.net/item/drupal-drag-drop-builder/12014058

I just want to know if is there a similar module to this but free, at the drupal proyect page. I know there is the panel module, but it is not the same , since this module is field based. You can add it as a field in any content type. This is very useful imho.

Comment: That module claims to come with "6 months free support", so I guess the two important things are: 1. why would you ask here rather than ask their support? 2. What sort of questions would you be asking about the module? That last one is the most important, as long as the question is on topic for the site (as in the usual stuff in the help center), I don't see why there would be a problem. Context is everything though, give us an idea of what you would be asking about it

Comment: I just want to know if is there a similar module to this but free, at the drupal proyect page. I know there is the panel module, but it is not the same , since this module is field based. You can add it as a field in any content type. This is very useful imho.

Comment: @chefnelone Requests for modules are one of the things forbidden. "Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers" as close reason states.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing *inherently* bad with such questions, but there are certain kinds that can go wrong way easier:

1. *"Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers."*, close reason states, so things like "What  is a free alternative?" would be off-topic - just like any other module request.
2. Questions are only good if they are useful for future readers. If module price includes support to everyone who bought it, probably question will not be useful here - because anyone interested can get better answer closer to the source.
3. Questions are only good if it's legal to ask them. If you ask about module's code without posting said code, it will be closed as too broad or something like that, and if you will provide this code, you will break copyright and they can sue you.
4. Questions are only good if it is legal to answer them. If module authors set a price for support, it is possible that their license forbids other parties to provide support.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  What about this "I just want to know if is there a similar module but free" this is answerable question imho. It is like "is there a module to add the EU Cookies message in my site?"

Comment: @chefnelone module recommendations got banned altogether, it seems. Close reason makes no dostinction between ways you ask for module recommendations now. It was different (less strict) few months ago, true, but now it is what it is and change must have been made by powers higher than us ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends from the question, but in general it is valid what is valid for any other modules.

1. If you want us to recommend a module, that is off-topic
2. If you want to know how to change settings or how to set the module for a specific use, that is on-topic
3. If you want to ask how to alter the behavior of a module, that is on-topic, but we would need to see the code you implemented so far